# conic Lagrangian submanifold with boundary

Tags: symplectic-geometry

I'm reading through the paper "Lagrangian Intersection and the Cauchy Problem" by Melrose and Uhlmann, and I'm having trouble with the definition of intersecting pair of Lagrangian manifolds.

[image]

I am aware of the definition of [conic Lagrangian manifold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVXdR.png), but what is a conic Lagrangian manifold with boundary? Do we require the boundary to be isotropic or is it that if a conic Lagrangian submanifold has boundary then the boundary is always isotropic, or do we just define it to be such that the interior is a conic Lagrangian submanifold?